# ASUS F550LN Touch Pad Problem

Tags: touchpad, asus

I recently installed the newest stable release of Ubuntu on my ASUS F550LN and I can't get the touch pad to work. Well, it works for a single split-second once every 10 seconds circa. I can also use a mouse, but only to move the cursor, I can't click at all.

I am fairly new to Linux and I would like to be able to use Ubuntu with my touch pad.

I don't know what more to include here, so sorry if there is some important information I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are occasionally, some drivers which require a little extra to work properly.  Try this:  Open a terminal window, and enter `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree` This will load firmware (drivers) which are not usually distributed because the source code is not available.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary fix is to boot with "psmouse.proto=bare" on the kernel cmdline.

```
$ sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to add psmouse.proto=bare at the end, and save your modifications.

Then:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

And finally reboot.